# Android Jetpack Compose Autofill Framework - Google Generate Strong Password

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, autofill

I've used Google One Tap Sign in, but I wanted to try using Autofill this time. I created a custom Compose modifier:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
fun Modifier.autofill(
    autofillTypes: List<AutofillType>,
    onFill: ((String) -> Unit),
) = composed {
    val autofill = LocalAutofill.current
    val autofillNode = AutofillNode(onFill = onFill, autofillTypes = autofillTypes)
    LocalAutofillTree.current += autofillNode

    this
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            autofillNode.boundingBox = it.boundsInWindow()
        }
        .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
            autofill?.run {
                if (focusState.isFocused) {
                    requestAutofillForNode(autofillNode)
                } else {
                    cancelAutofillForNode(autofillNode)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
OutlinedTextField(
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
            value = userUIState.password,
            onValueChange = { userUIState.onPasswordChanged(it) },
            trailingIcon = {
                val iconState =
                    if (passwordVisible) Pair(R.drawable.visibility, "Hide password")
                    else Pair(R.drawable.visibility_off, "Show password")

                IconButton(onClick = { passwordVisible = !passwordVisible }) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = iconState.first),
                        iconState.second
                    )
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                .autofill(
                    autofillTypes = listOf(AutofillType.Password),
                    onFill = { userUIState.onPasswordChanged(it) },
                ),
            visualTransformation = if (passwordVisible) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation()
        )
```

It prompts me to open Google Password Manager, so I can 'suggest a strong password', which is great! BUT - when I add a username, then click 'Save', the suggested password isn't sent back to my text field.

On the other hand, this is working when I use `listOf(AutofillType.EmailAddress)`, so it seems to be something that's just related to suggesting a strong password.

I did find this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176949051, and ppl are having issues, but the reason that I'm posting is because I can't even get this to work in a traditional XML app:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:importantForAutofill="yes"
            android:autofillHints="password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

Here, again, the 'suggested password' doesn't come back to the field. I've enabled Logging in developer options, but that didn't provide much help:

```
2023-06-15 15:50:31.946 22063-22063 AutofillManager         com.santansarah.barcodescanner       V  client is visible, check tracked ids
2023-06-15 15:50:31.947 22063-22063 Activity                com.santansarah.barcodescanner       V  autofillClientGetViewVisibility(): [true, true]
2023-06-15 15:50:31.947 22063-22063 AutofillManager         com.santansarah.barcodescanner       V  TrackedViews(trackedIds=[1073741825:1, 1073741825:2]):  mVisibleTrackedIds={1073741825:1, 1073741825:2} mInvisibleTrackedIds=null
2023-06-15 15:50:31.947 22063-22063 AutofillManager         com.santansarah.barcodescanner       V  notifyCallback(): sessionId=385461512, autofillId=1073741825:11@385461512, event=1
2023-06-15 15:51:09.452 22063-22063 AutofillManager         com.santansarah.barcodescanner       D  onAuthenticationResult(): id= 18743299, data=null
2023-06-15 15:51:09.455 22063-22063 PhoneWindow             com.santansarah.barcodescanner       V  DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@743175d, this = DecorView@cf3be46[MainActivity]
2023-06-15 15:51:09.494 22063-22063 RecordingIC             com.santansarah.barcodescanner       W  requestCursorUpdates is not supported
```

Maybe my issue is here? `onAuthenticationResult(): id= 18743299, data=null` - the data is null?
I'm just wondering if anyone has this working - I feel like I might be missing some sort of callback or something. That being said, I tried this, but it just brings back an id:

```
val test = object: AutofillManager.AutofillCallback() {
    override fun onAutofillEvent(view: View, event: Int) {
        super.onAutofillEvent(view, event)
        Timber.d("autofill event: $event")
    }
}
```

Here's my playground branch w/everything that I've tried: https://github.com/santansarah/barcode-scanner/tree/autofill-playground (it's kindof a mess right now; I tested all sorts of things).

Any help is appreciated - thanks :)!